# How do I prevent multiple subscription calls in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, subscription

I have a message service, to interact between various components. I just want to trigger a message, when I click on the `Mine` button. This works so far. But when I click on the `<` and `>`button, it triggers `getMessage()`, so that it adds up values. But I just want to send one value, when I click on `Mine`. The last value only. How do I prevent to trigger `getMessage()`, when clicking on `<`and `>`?

When I click on `<`and `>`it switches between the cards from 1 to 10. When I click on `Mine` it should only take the card which I'm on and send the information from that block to another component. But instead, when I click `<`or `>`, `getMessage()`is getting called and it adds up all cards until I click `Mine`. How do I prevent that?

Following some code. I tried to keep it compact:

Message-service.ts:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MessageService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  sendMessage(message: string) {
    this.subject.next({ text: message });
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Get Message Message Service');
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
```

Miner-card.component:

```
  message: any;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private emitTransactionService: EmitTransactionService,
              private messageService: MessageService) {
    this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
      console.log('Constructor miner-card'); // gets called multiple times, depending on how often I click < and >. When I click 10 times on < or > it will call this subscription 10 times.
    });
  }
```

When I click on `<`and `>`, these functions are getting called:
Depending on the value of minerCounter, card 1-10 are getting displayed.

```
  precedingBlock() {
    this.minerCounter--;

    if (this.minerCounter < 1) {
      this.minerCounter = 10;
    }
  }

  nextBlock() {
    this.minerCounter++;

    if (this.minerCounter > 10) {
      this.minerCounter = 1;
    }
  }
```

How the card looks like with the `<`and `>`buttons:

[image]

The `Mine` button:

[image]

Comment: take(1) operator will solve your problem use that in subscribe

Comment: can you also add what function you are calling when the `<` or `>` are clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should  always `unsubscribe` the subscription in `ngOnDestroy`.

```
  message: any;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private emitTransactionService: EmitTransactionService,
              private messageService: MessageService) {
    this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
      console.log('Constructor miner-card'); // gets called multiple times, depending on how often I click < and >. When I click 10 times on < or > it will call this subscription 10 times.
    });
  }

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: I used that too already. If I click 5 times on < or >, it still gets called 5 times when I click on 'Mine'

Comment: have you tried to unsubscribe the subscription on ngOnDestroy

Comment: Yes thanks. Write that in your answer and I will give u the green tick :)

Answer (score 1):

check if your subscription is undefined or not. If undefined, only then subscribe.

```
constructor(
private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
private emitTransactionService: EmitTransactionService,
private messageService: MessageService
) {
if (!this.subscription) {
    this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
      console.log('Constructor miner-card'); // gets called multiple times, depending on how often I click < and >. When I click 10 times on < or > it will call this subscription 10 times.
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Buddy, you should probably consider creating a StackBlitz. It will help us resolve your issue sooner.

Answer (score 1):

In your `miner-card.component.ts` file use `take(1)`. this will get only single data from the subscribe.

```
  message: any;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private emitTransactionService: EmitTransactionService,
              private messageService: MessageService) {
    this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(message => {
      console.log('Constructor miner-card'); // gets called multiple times, depending on how often I click < and >. When I click 10 times on < or > it will call this subscription 10 times.
    });
  }
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: I imported import { take } from 'rxjs/operators'; and have the same code as you at the moment. But it say unresolved function take(1).

Comment: if you are using rxjs latest version then you need to use pipe. check updated answer